# Viewlifecycleowner is not found in Fragment

Tags: android-activity, android-livedata

I want to observe livedata with

`viewlifecycleowner`

instead of

```
this
```

but it is not resolved. What is the dependency for it?

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle

```
    // LiveData
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
// Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
```